# Windows Firewall Rule still being applied after being deleted

Tags: windows, networking, firewall, windows-firewall

I recently created an outbound rule to block an executable's traffic however, when I deleted the rule, the firewall was still blocking the application. I did a little digging and although I couldnt see it in the outbound list, I could see it in `Active Firewall Rules`. Here are some screenshots:

- Active Firewall Rules Location

[image: Active Firewall Rules Location]

- Active Rule still in effect after deletion  (This is not the actual rule, the actual rule was outbound and has now gone after a system reboot)

[image: Active Rule still in effect after deletion]

The only way I found to stop this was to rename the executable / change its path, or to restart the machine.

I have not found this behaviour when working with port numbers. My guess is that the firewall binds something to the process and thus it cant remove the rule until the process has terminated? (This would be strange though as I could not see the process still running on the machine)

Does anyone have any insight as to why this is the case or if it even is the case? And is it preferred to use port numbers rather than manage an applications connections directly?

Comment: In your second screenshot those rules are also visible. Did you try to delete those?

Comment: I don't appear to have the ability to delete anything in the active rules list.

Comment: This is not a window that you are able to manage rules in. Pressing the delete key when selecting an entry does nothing and the action window on the right also does not show any actions relating to managing the relevant entry.

Comment: Is this a domain computer and/or do you have admin rights on the computer?

Comment: There is no domain and the user account is an administrator.